# Spring boot WebClient asynchronous call

Tags: java, spring, webclient, resttemplate, spring-webclient

Spring `WebClient` is a reactive client that provides an alternative to `RestTemplate`. It is said that it's asynchronous.

But when i am using normal `WebClient` without subscribe it working fine but adding subscribe for asynchronous(Non-blocking) not getting api response.

Code Snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main method");
        System.out.println("Before Sync call");
        System.out.println("Res :" + getDataSync());
        System.out.println("After Sync call");
        System.out.println("Before Async call");
        getDataAsync().subscribe(res -> System.out.println(res));
        System.out.println("After Async call");
    }

    public static Mono<String> getDataAsync() {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("https://reqres.in");
        System.out.println("Inside Async");
        return webClient.get().uri("api/users").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }

    public static String getDataSync() {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("https://reqres.in");

        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = webClient.get().uri("api/users").retrieve();
        return responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block();
    }
```

Output:

```
Main method
Before Sync call
Res :{"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"george.bluth@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"},{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"},{"id":3,"email":"emma.wong@reqres.in","first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"},{"id":4,"email":"eve.holt@reqres.in","first_name":"Eve","last_name":"Holt","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"},{"id":5,"email":"charles.morris@reqres.in","first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Morris","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"},{"id":6,"email":"tracey.ramos@reqres.in","first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Ramos","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"}],"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}
After Sync call
Before Async call
Inside Async
After Async call
```

Screenshot

[Code and Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgeAt.png)

I want to implement asynchronous call with Spring `WebClient`. Please help to get it resolve.

Comment: what is the problem you faced with?

Comment: Not getting api response in asynchronous call.

Comment: you should get it, but the main finishes earlier. try to add `Thread.sleep(1000L)`  at the end of main and you should see the result